# Delete lines below, excluding the line with match pattern

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed

One can use `sed '/pattern/Q'` or `sed '/pattern/,$d'` to delete lines below a match pattern, but it also deletes the line containing the match pattern.

How to exclude the line containing the match pattern, and only delete the lines below it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-complicating this by using `Q`, which is one of the [Commands Specific to GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Extended-Commands):

> Q [exit-code]
>
> This command accepts only one address.
>
> This command is the same as q, but will not print the contents of pattern space. Like q, it provides the ability to return an exit code to the caller.

If you **don't** want this special behaviour (i.e. you **do** want to print the contents of the matched pattern space before quitting), use the regular `q` command:

```
sed '/pattern/q'
```

Comment: Thank you; I see now that `sed '/pattern/Q'` deletes the line with match pattern as well as the lines below it, while  `sed '/pattern/q'` deletes simply the lines *below* it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
sed -n '/pattern/{p;q};p'
```

The `-n` switch tells `sed` not to print by default.

The `{p;q}` says that if the pattern is observed, print the line and quit.

The `;p` is the default action when no match has been found yet, and that is to print.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1,/pattern/'
```

The following command would print nothing if `pattern` is not found.

```
$ awk '{a = a $0 ORS}/pattern/{printf "%s", a}'
```

---

Using `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -M "(.*\n)*.*pattern"
```

Answer (score 1):

awk is a better choice than sed for tasks like this for simplicity, clarity and portability, e.g. to delete all lines below some line that matches a regexp (a `3` in this case):

```
$ seq 10 | awk '{print} /3/{exit}'
1
2
3
```

or if you want to also delete the matching line then move where the regexp is tested to before instead of after the print:

```
$ seq 10 | awk '/3/{exit} {print}'
1
2
```

or we can delete the 4 lines after a 3 appears by:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR>n{print} /3/{n=NR+4}'
1
2
3
8
9
10
```

or alternatively using idiom "f" from [printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908555/printing-with-sed-or-awk-a-line-following-a-matching-pattern/17914105#17914105):

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'c&&c--{next} /3/{c=4} {print}'
1
2
3
8
9
10
```

Those commands will all work using any awk on every Unix box and it's trivial to do anything similar you may want to do.

Comment: Thank you so much; it will be like a Swiss Knife if you could add another option after the last two examples:  deleting *1 line before and 4 lines after* a 3 appears.

Comment: @Sadi you already accepted an answer to this question so if you want to build on that then you should ask the person who provided that answer, if anyone, but you should really just ask a new question as [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are strongly discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Perl**:

```bash
~$ seq 10 | perl -pe 'last if /3/'
1
2

#OR:

~$ seq 10 | raku -ne '/3/ ? last : print $_;'
1
2
```

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6):

```bash
~$ seq 10 | perl -pe 'last if /3/'
1
2

#OR:

~$ seq 10 | raku -ne '/3/ ?? (last) !! (put $_);'
1
2
```

Perl and Raku borrow many of the command-line flage conventions from `sed` and `awk`. Above the `-pe` flags run the code linewise over input *with* autoprinting; the `-ne` flags run the code linewise over input *without* autoprinting. In all four answers above `last` is used exit the linewise loop. There are minor differences between Perl and Raku's ternary operators, chiefly because Raku deploys the `:` colon for other aspects of the language.

https://perldoc.perl.org
https://docs.raku.org